# Get "current" rows count from table

Tags: postgresql

One transaction inserts into `some_table`. Large data inserted so it running few minutes.

While insertion happens, if do from another transaction:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM some_table;
```

it shows row count before insertion started, right?

Question: Is there any way, to check `current` row count in table? so it would count, what rows already inserted by first transaction too, for this moment. Is this even possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. A transaction isn't saved to the database until commit and a transaction isn't view-able by any other session.

Of course I could be wrong but I can't think of a way of doing that.

Comment: The second transaction cannot see rows created by the first transaction until the first transaction commits. Until then those rows do not exist (except within transaction 1). That's basic to the MVCC design of Postgres. Now suppose you could get the count you've asked and that transaction has inserted 1000's of rows, so you get them in the count during transaction 2. Now an error occurs and transaction 1 issues rollback. Transaction 2 has reported the wrong number of rows.

Comment: @Belayer - Of course, by nature of transaction, this is really way, what should happened. I just needed if there is some way, to get "current" rows, for testing purposes only (so first transaction during time is big, and let's check how many rows currently inserted, so cancel first transaction, or wait for finish?)

Comment: @Belayer - Of course it is not acceptable to use  that data in production or something...

Comment: But there is actually no such thing as "current" only committed. Postgres does NOT permit read uncommitted.

Comment: @Belayer - Yes, got it. Thanks.

Comment: The reality is that some batch inserts take a while. Can you split it into sections perhaps? Also how often does it actually fail? If only very rare then not so much of a worry, if often then why and do you need some more work on the data before you try an insert.